# Python : Selenium - Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, linux, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to start chrome driver in Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7 using selenium with python. Also got some useful help from the [chrome documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), my extract code snippet is

```
chromedriver = "/path/to/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,
              service_log_path = service_log_path, service_args=service_args)
```

But I am getting the error message below,

> Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7

I dont see a problem in the code (as far as I know), please help me with some fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 'Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596402/selenium-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-error)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if you made your chromedriver executable ( on a Ubuntu/Linux/Mac system). If you didn't do that, your chromedriver wouldn't work.

Please try this - if you haven't

```
 chmod +x chromedriver

 chmod 777 chromedriver
```

And then try again. I wrote a simple script for this and I was able to get my chrome started perfectly -

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path="/home/rahul/Documents/SeleniumPy/chromedriver" //this is my chromedriver path

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My permissions with chromedriver is fine '-rwxr-xr-x' - it has execution permissions for all users. Just now tried your snippet and still the same error.

Comment: Never chmod 777 anything!