# Selenium 'Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally' error

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am following https://github.com/RobCherry/docker-chromedriver/blob/master/Dockerfile as an example and I have the following in my docker file:

```
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DISPLAY :20.0
ENV SCREEN_GEOMETRY "1440x900x24"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''
EXPOSE 4444
```

To create the driver I am doing:

```
webdriver.Chrome()
```

But I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.27-boot2docker x86_64)
```

Do I have to do anything else to allow Chrome to start?

Answer (score 33):

Got it working. The key is to add:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The flag that made the difference for me when running Chrome headless in a Docker instance was actually `no-sandbox` - If I leave it out Selenium fails with `ERROR: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: Are you on VPS on on a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working just by adding -

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```