# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

So I have the exact same error as these posts

[Selenium 'Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596402/selenium-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-error)

[Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424737/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally)

I tried what they recommended and it didn't work.

Here is my code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://nytimes.com')
print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

And here is the full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumtest.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)
```

What the devil am I doing wrong? I'm running this on an ubuntu VPS on digitalocean.

Comment: you normally wouldn't need headless chrome if already in a headless virtualdisplay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

There are exactly two *incompatibility* issues as discussed below.

---

### disable-gpu

When *Headless Chrome* was first released as *GA (General Availability)* by *Google Team* the article [`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) mentioned that :

```
--disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

A note was added as :

> Right now, you'll also want to include the `--disable-gpu` flag if you're running on Windows.

As per the discussion [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) it was clear that :

> The `--disable-gpu` flag is no longer necessary on *Linux* or *Mac OSX*. It will also become unnecessary on Windows as soon as the bug [SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) is fixed. Now as this issue is marked **fixed** the argument `--disable-gpu` should be redundant now.

**Note**: You can find a detailed discussion in [ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-ini/50148698#50148698)

---

However, your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.30*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.30*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v58-60**

- Your *chrome* version is unknown to us. Assuming you are using on of the latest *Chrome* releases either among:

  - `Chrome version 71`
  - `Chrome version 72`
  - `Chrome version 73`

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.30* and the *Chrome Browser v71-73*

### Solution

- Depending on your *Chrome Browser* version upgrade *ChromeDriver* accordingly following the [guidelines](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) below:

  - If you are using *Chrome version 73*, you need to download *ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20*
  - If you are using *Chrome version 72*, you need to download *ChromeDriver 2.46* or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69
  - If you are using *Chrome version 71*, you need to download *ChromeDriver 2.46* or ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137
  - For older version of *Chrome*, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748) for the version of *ChromeDriver* that supports it.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally while executing tests through Selenium start on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720561/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exite/51720913#51720913)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium on debian server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475757/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/57477596#57477596)
- [Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally on AWS Cloud9 with Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027278/message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-on-aws-cloud9/50027645#50027645)

Comment: Thank you!! That was it exactly- I had an old version of chromedriver. No idea how I managed to install an old version since I installed it today but not matter. Works now!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your browser's version, but chromedriver 2.30 is *pretty* old - circa June 2017; Chrome was version 59 then, and at 72 now. *([yes, I checked, it's not like I know their release history by heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) )*

I'd suggest to upgrade it to a recent version - or to one matching your installed browser.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, I upgraded to a 2.46 and it worked!